# How to move content part to another zone?

Tags: orchardcms

I want to move `RoutableTitle` part from `Content` zone to `BeforeMain` zone. Is it possible?

**Update**
Here is the official answer http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/267838

Answer (score 1):

The default `placement.info` for Routable (under Orchard.Web\Core\Routeable) has the following entries:

```
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_RoutableTitle="Header:5"/>
</Match>
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_RoutableTitle_Summary="Header:5"/>
</Match>
```

In your theme, you should have your own `placement.info` file, so add these entries. The `Place` tag has the following format:

```
<Place Shape_Name="Zone:Order" />
```

So the following should do the trick:

```
<Place Parts_RoutableTitle="BeforeMain:1" />
```

And of course you may need to adjust the order parameter to your taste.

Comment: This does not work. Try yourself with default theme (TheThemeMachine).

Comment: Can you post your placement.info, and details of where you have inserted it (theme, module etc?)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having issues overriding the routable placement in a module.